# Adobe Flash Player crashes all browsers OSx 10.9.1 Mavericks! Why?

Tags: macos, adobe-flash

Adobe Flash Player crashes all browsers OSx 10.9.1 Mavericks! Firefox, Safari, Chrome, or NetNewsWire. Why?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the Player software, then restarting? Please provide more details about what you've tried to do to fix the situation, then report back. The latest Flash Player works just fine on the 5 Macs, (2 iMacs, 1 Server, 1 MBAir,) that I use on a daily basis. (I wish I didn't have to use Flash, but that's a discussion for another day.)

Comment: In addition, does this happen for all user accounts or only for your own? If you don't have several users, you could create a new one and try to use Flash. Any results here will help in determining whether the issue is related to your Mac in general or to some settings in your account.

Comment: I don't have an answer, as I have the very same problem. Using MacOS 10.9.2, the latest Adobe Flash Player update 13.0.0.182 crashes in Safari 7.0.3 and Firefox 26.0. Everything worked fine until the .182 update, then nothing works. Have reinstalled multiple times, uninstalled and reinstalled, cleared all caches with AppleJack, and the problem affects all user accounts on this system.

Answer (score 2):

Since google chrome embeds it's own version of flash - it doesn't use the system version. Rather than chasing three problems, why not uninstall the system flash, run updates on Google Chrome and see if the crash clears up?

It's also going to be more difficult for a good answer to be provided without details on your OS version, the version of the one browser you want to focus on first and perhaps a link to a web page that causes the crash.

Comment: Nicely said (+1) for that